# clojurescript core.async - tell if mouse is down while mouseover

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I am looking for a nice way of only responding to mouseover events but only when the mouse is down.  I'm looking for a more core.async way of doing this.

I have two channels in an om component:

```
om/IDidMount
(did-mount [_]
  (let [canvas (q ".tutorial")
        _ref (js/Firebase. "https://conseal.firebaseio.com/scribble")
        ctx (.getContext canvas "2d")
        mouse-down (om/get-state owner :mouse-down)
        mouse-chan (om/get-state owner :mouse-chan)]

    (listen canvas EventType.MOUSEDOWN #(put! mouse-down [:down %]))
    (listen canvas EventType.MOUSEMOVE #(put! mouse-chan [:move %]))
```

I then have the following `go-loop` in `IWillMount`:

```
om/IWillMount
(will-mount [_]
  (let [mouse-down (om/get-state owner :mouse-down)
        mouse-chan (om/get-state owner :mouse-chan) ]
    (go-loop []
      (<! mouse-down)
      (let [[evt-type e] (<! mouse-chan)]
          (.log js/console (str evt-type " we are over " e)))
      (recur))))
```

The above does not work because `mousedown` events are not continually sent.  I'm looking for a `core.async` idiomatic way of handling this.

If I was using rxjs I could do something like this:

```
var mouseDrags = mouseDowns.select(function (downEvent) {
    return mouseMoves.takeUntil(mouseUps).select(function (drag) {
        return functionToGetStuffWeWant(drag);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your current code structure, one way to do this is to add a mouse-up channel (or combine this with mouse-down into a mouse-buttons channel or something).

Then in your go loop, use the following logic:

1. Read from `mouse-down` and `mouse-channel` (using `alt`).  If `mouse-channel` was read, ignore the value and loop (to 1).  If `mouse-down` was read, break out of the loop and continue with 2.
2. Read from `mouse-up` and `mouse-channel`.  If `mouse`channel`was read, process the current position and loop (to 2).  If`mouse-up` was read, break out of the inner loop, and loop back to 1.

To put this in concrete terms, you might do something like this (untested):

```
(go-loop []
  (loop []
    (alt! [mouse-down] down nil ;; stop looping when mouse-down is read
          [mouse-channel] event (recur))) ;; loop until mouse-down
  (loop []
    (alt! [mouse-up] up nil ;; stop looping when mouse-up is read
          [mouse-chan] event ;; process current position
            (do
              (.log js/console (str evt-type " we are over " event))
              (recur)))) ;; loop until mouse-up
  (recur)) ;; start the process all over again
```

For robustness, you may want to read from `mouse-up` in the first loop and `mouse-down` in the second loop, in case there are ever two consecutive mouse-up (or mouse-down) events.  Otherwise, it's possible for them to get out of sync.  In both cases, simply discard the value and `recur`.

On the other hand, you may prefer an approach similar to your rxjs example.  In this case, note that several of the seq operations (`map`, `take`, etc) from core clojure have channel analogs in `core.async`.  However, I don't think `take-until` is one of them.  Still, it should be pretty easy to implement your own version of `take-until` that operates over channels.